# How is a relative clause reduced to " fertile ground in which to grow"?

Tags: relative-clauses

> As long as the leadership of the physics community refuses to accept that string theory is a "failed project", he writes, "**there is little likelihood of new ideas finding fertile ground in which to grow**". (A sentence from an ACT test)

Regarding the bold part, I know "in which" is equivalent to "where", which acts as a relative clause; but I am not aware of the usage when a clause can be reduced into an infinitive "to grow", will it make more sense to say "in which they grow"?

Comment: No, that would change the meaning. "in which to grow" is an infinitival relative clause that has the modal meaning "in which it can grow".

Comment: Thanks, I suddenly recall it. But I think an infinitival relative clause does not need "in which", just "there is little likelihood of new ideas finding fertile ground to grow"

Comment: It does need the "in which".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *There is little likelihood of new ideas finding fertile ground* [*in*
> *which to grow*].

No, "in which they grow" would change the meaning to one that wouldn't make much sense here.

"In which to grow" is an infinitival relative clause that has the modal meaning comparable to that expressed in finites by "can" or "could". The relative clause in your example can thus be paraphrased as "in which they can/could grow".